# Motto About Chaos

Tags: contemporary-latin

I want a latin motto that expresses "Out of chaos, software"   Or "From chaos, software".  I know software is a strange concept for Latin.   Any suggestions?

Comment: Wiktionary uses 'corpus programmatum' for its article about software https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_programmatum. This motto is presumably based on the Masonic 'ordo ab chao' 'order out of chaos'.

Answer (score 6):

To say "Out of Chaos", it's pretty simply *Ex Chao*.

Software is another story.

Pretty much all of the translations I can find are related to the word program. Firstly, Wiktionary lists programmatura, meaning basically "programming", or maybe like, "programmature" if you like strange English.

Neo-Latin Lexicon's *Silva* gives a translation of "Partes programmationes", meaning "parts of programming", which is a bit of a clunky phrase, and might not be what you want. Vicipaedia uses "corpus programmatum", meaning perhaps "programmed body", presumably in contrast with the physical body of the computer, though I'm not sure.

Two places I like that are dedicated to New Latin computer terminology are *Vocabula Computatralia* and *Computatoria*. Vocabula Computatralia says to use the word for program as the word for software, while Computatoria says to use the plural of program.

That leaves us with five options for software:

1. partes programmationes
2. corpus programmatum
3. programma
4. programmata
5. programmatura

I should note that Vicipaedia uses "Programma Computatrale" for "Computer Program" and "Programmatura Computatralis" as "Computer Programming". However, Vicipaedia does not per se have authority over New Latin or Latin in the modern world—These are simply usages to keep in mind.

Personally, I'd go with one of the last three. The first two are clunky, so maybe as hyperspecific or technical terms they work, but I do not think they'd sound nice in a motto.

I hope I did not provide a confusing amount of information to you, and I hope you found this all helpful.

Comment: Nice answer - welcome to the site!